# Check if a method is defined in the base or derived class

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance

I want to have a function to tell me whether `test` is the original version from the base class or a new version implemented in the derived class. I found that `inspect.getfullargspec` might be able to solve my issue, but it doesn't work with Python 3 which is needed for my case.

```
class base_class(object):
    @staticmethod 
    def test(a, b, c):
        pass

class child_class(base_class):
    @staticmethod
    def test(a, b):
        pass 

class child_class_2(base_class):
    pass
```

Comment: Not sure why the close vote. Seems pretty clear to me...

Comment: If it matters which class `test` comes from, then inheritance probably isn't the right choice to model whatever it is you are doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any fancy inspection to do this:

```
>>> x = child_class_2()                                                     
>>> x.test                                                                  
<function base_class.test at 0x7fea1a07f7b8>

>>> y = child_class()                                                       
>>> y.test                                                                  
<function child_class.test at 0x7fea1a07f950>
```

The printed name comes from the `__qualname__` attribute of the function by default:

```
>>> x.test.__qualname__
base_class.test
>>> y.test.__qualname__
child_class.test
```

A hacky way to get the name of the class is

```
x.test.__qualname__[:-len(x.test.__name__) - 1]
```

Comment: Is that IPython output? That doesn't look like a normal Python function `__repr__`.

Comment: Actually, even IPython shouldn't display what you're showing for `x.test.__qualname__`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am getting AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__qualname__'

Comment: @user2357112 IPython 7.5.0 running a Python 3.7.3 kernel. Sorry about that. I changed to regular python now.

Comment: @Lemon. What version of Python are you on? `__qualname__` was added in 3.3.

Comment: I see. I am on python 2.7.5

Comment: @Lemon. I inferred that you were using Python 3 based on "but it doesn't work with Python 3 which is needed for my case."

Comment: @Lemon. Please remove that sentence and add the appropriate language tags to your question if you want a Python-2.x answer.